# Using np.genfromtxt() to get data from a text file is limited by the number of colums in the file?

Tags: python

I´m using np.genfromtxt to get data from a text file but I can´t understand this error message:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('ctr_tr3.txt', skip_header=2, names=True)

a=data['PO4']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EclipseIndigoWorkspace\W2\src\Import.py", line 55, in <module>
    data = np.genfromtxt('ctr_tr3.txt', skip_header=2, names=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1560, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #4 (got 10 columns instead of 11)
    Line #5 (got 10 columns instead of 11)
    Line #6 (got 10 columns instead of 11)
    Line #7 (got 10 columns instead of 11)
    Line #8 (got 10 columns instead of 11)
    Line #9 (got 10 columns instead of 11)
```

Comment: It is relatively clear, the lines mentioned have 10 columns while apparently it is expecting 11 because the third has 11, check your third line.

Comment: yes the third line had 11. thank you